# Phonegap Android HTML wont update

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am trying to upload some code html and javascript code into phonegap to develop this app however when I update the files the program still runs the old code as to what was in the html file before. I have even started a new project and it will not change the old index.html image even though the code behind it is different. I'm really confused as to why this is and I was wondering what I could do to solve this. I even searched through the workspace index.html file and it is the correct file that I want in there but upon running it i am given the same your device is ready hello world. I checked the location of the files and everything is correct. It is very confusing. I am using eclipse by the way not phonegap build if that helps.

Comment: I had similar problem with phoneGap in eclipse, so I used Adobe dreamweaver cs6 which has a great support for mobile apps. it may be not the best solution but it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

you need to build your project again.

```
cordova build android
```

But make sure you edit your files in www folder in parent folder.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are updating the WWW file in the root Phonegap folder. Then you can run the command:

```
$ cordova build
```

or

```
$ phonegap build
```